# Why alaw generates noise and ulaw does not

Tags: encoding, sample, noise

I use socket to send some voice data to another PC and I encoded my data before sending it using ALAW with this "setup":

```
AudioFormat.Encoding.ALAW, 
8000.0f        // sampleRate
8,             // sampleSizeInBits
1,             // channels
1,             // frameSize
8000.0f,       // frameRate
false);        // bigEndian
```

The problem is, it generates a small (but quite annoying) noise at receiver side when I don't speak anything at the microphone. When I speak, the noise is almost gone but not entirely.

When I change to ULAW (exactly same "setup") the noise doesn't exist at all, the sound is very clear.

Is there anything I can do about that? Is there any recommended setup to use along with ALAW? I really need to stick to ALAW because ULAW causes me some mess in the code (and too much modifications would be necessary).

Side note: I printed the buffer and without speaking to microphone it has lots of 8,-1,8,-1,8,0,8,0 type of pattern. I tried to force all 8 to become 0 but still not big difference. I tried that because with ULAW there are many 0's when I don't speak instead of 8's as for ALAW. This pattern that I'm talking about is from the (convert ALAW to PCM) PCM before being sent for playing by sound card.
I took conversion algorithm from here if it is important: [ALAW PCM  Conversions](https://svn.typo3.org/TYPO3v4/Extensions/jclic_ef/JClic_ef/src/org/tritonus/share/sampled/TConversionTool.java)

Answer (score 2):

Check the silence suppression settings. And be shure that there is not some implicit codec conversion.

> **A-law vs u-Law** A-law and u-law are two algorithms that are used in modifying an input signal for digitization. These algorithms are
>   implemented in telephony systems all over the world. The two
>   algorithms have a fairly minimal difference and most people would not
>   know the difference. The first difference between the two is the
>   dynamic range of the ouput; U-law has a larger dynamic range than
>   a-law. Dynamic range is basically the ratio between the quietest and
>   loudest sound that can be represented in the signal. The downside of
>   having a higher dynamic range is greater distortion of small signals.
>   This simply means that a-law would sound better than u-law when the
>   sound input is very soft.

Read more: Difference Between A-law and u-Law | Difference Between | A-law vs u-Law http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-a-law-and-u-law/#ixzz3eIfw2LtV

Comment: Where may I check for the silence suppression settings? By implicit codec you mean built in by jdk when using ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(PCMFormat, ais) ? Because if so, that may be the problem as I use both that command and the algorithms that I post a link (edited) and there may be a difference between them. But I can't discard any of them as the first is mandatory and I also need the external algorithm for some  other operations.

Comment: in your java code do you specify the same codec ? If not it's possible that some default codec is involved and so  there is some auto conversion.

Comment: Yes I specify AudioFormat.Encoding.ALAW with all that setup posted above. Seems like, as you said, voice activation detection is activated, but why only for ALAW  and not for ULAW? And how may I deactivate it?

Comment: I suggest you to double check your code and confiugrations. It seems there is no issue with alaw. Use the latest library, check everything and retry.